How to get typing animation to not start at beginning?
I am trying to create a text reveal typing effect, but right now the text starts at the very beginning. How can I change it so that the text starts at the center and ends up centered within the gray bubble after the animation?



.text-typing {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  width: 25%;
  margin: auto;
}

.text-typing h2 {
  margin: 0px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0);
  animation: typing 4s steps(22, end) forwards, blink 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes typing {
  0% {
    width: 0%
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%
  }
}

@keyframes blink {
  0%,
  100% {
    border-right: 2px solid transparent;
  }
  50% {
    border-right: 2px solid #222;
  }
}
<div class="text-typing">
  <h2>Experience</h2>
</div>



I have tried to change the animation itself but don't know which part would make it so that it starts not at the very beginning.

Set 0% keyframe width to more then 0.

@Kiraa tried that, doesn't seem to work

Here's my updated answer:


.text-typing {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  width: 25%;
  margin: auto;
  /*new code from here*/
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  /*to fix the blinking at the ending of the "e": */
  width: 118px;
}

.text-typing h2 {
  margin: 0px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0);
  animation: typing 4s steps(22, end) forwards;
}

.text-typing:after {
  animation: blink 1s forwards infinite;
  content: '';
  /*here you can adjust the height*/
  height: 20px;
}

@keyframes typing {
  0% {
    width: 0%
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%
  }
}

@keyframes blink {
  0%,
  100% {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
  }
  50% {
    border: 1px solid #222;
  }
}
<div class="text-typing">
  <h2>Experience</h2>
</div>




No, I want it to start typing the E at the center of the gray bubble

I've updated my answer. Please, take a look again.

Yes, that is very close to what I want. How can I make it so that the blinking stops moving forward as soon as it is done typing Experience? So it stays right beside the last 'e'

For that you have to add a max-width of 118px to the container, as I did in the new updated answer. (If I understood what you want)

Got it, thank you so much! One more thing, how can I adjust the height of the blinking cursor? right now it is longer in height than the word

I noticed that on mobile the content is barely visible, I fixed this with defining a fixed width. Now you can consider marking it as the chosen answer. Thank you in advance.
